# How do you make a string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

Complete the function 'interpolate'. This function will take in a string parameter, and return a string

I have put string data into the console log and called the function

I was expecting for the string of "I love lettuce"

```js
function interpolate(favoriteFood) {
  console.log("I love" + favoriteFood);
}
interpolate("lettuce");
```

Comment: And what went wrong? What are you stuck with? There's no actual question here.

Comment: This isn't interpolation.

Comment: And add a space here `"I love "` `console.log(\`I love ${favoriteFood}\`);`

Comment: Im on galvanize.com question 18 Im not sure if you could get to it but I keep getting back an error I dont know how they want it done becuase when I put it in the browser console it comes back correct

Comment: https://learn-2.galvanize.com/cohorts/888/blocks/215/content_files/placement_challenge.md

Comment: @Codekw The question says you're supposed to return a string from the function.  Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Amy I put the console.log to print "I love lettuce" it doesnt I even wanted to use return keyword. The issue with this assignment is that another console is reading it one part of a program I am taking and it is not giving me feedback positve feedback. When I print any of the console.log or return in my browser console it prints but not on the assignmnet webpage

Comment: You should *only* write to the console for *diagnostic* purposes.  Writing to the console is not returning anything.  `console.log` doesn't have a return value, either.

Answer (score 0):

look here for more information about [string interpolation](http://%5Ehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

this should do the trick:

`` console.log(`I love ${favoriteFood}`); ``

Comment: Im on galvanize.com question 18 Im not sure if you could get to it but I keep getting back an error I dont know how they want it done becuase when I put it in the browser console it comes back correct

Comment: https://learn-2.galvanize.com/cohorts/888/blocks/215/content_files/placement_challenge.md